# C++17 mutable lambda with capture *this and callback function gives "error C2100: illegal indirection"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, lambda, c++17

I come up with a `error C2100: illegal indirection` compiler error while trying to use a lambda function and the new C++17 functionality for capturing *this* by copy.

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
private:
    std::string myText;
public:
    void setText(std::string str)
    {
        myText = str;
    };

    std::function<void()> getPrintFunction(std::function<void(A&)> setter)
    {
        // C++17 capture this by copy
        return [*this, setter]() mutable {
            setter(*this);
            printMyText();
        };
    };
private:
    void printMyText()
    {
        std::cout << myText << std::endl;
    };
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    auto f = a.getPrintFunction([](A& a2) { a2.setText("Hello World"); });
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

This error doesn't seem to happen with the GCC compiler, so I don't know if my code is incorrect or is a just a problem with MSVC.

Comment: The code looks reasonable to me. It is likely a MSVC bug. This wouldn't be the first time that happened, either (see [Error in lambda capturing `this` by-copy](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/578791/error-in-lambda-capturing-this-by-copy-visual-stud.html)).

Comment: Ok, then i will report an error to the developer community of VisualStudio. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems a issue. A fix for this issue has been released! I suggest you should try to use the latest version of visual studio 2019 and try to use `/std:c++latest` instead of `/std:c++17` as it's about new lambda processor. It also works `/experimental:newLambdaProcessor`.